# Functorial factorisation in a double category

Tags: ct.category-theory

$\require{AMScd}$Let's consider a pseudo double category $\cal K$ (vertically strict, horizontally weak), with vertical category ${\cal K}_v$, and let's assume that ${\cal K}_v$ has a functorial orthogonal factorisation system $({\cal E}, {\cal M})$. This means, of course, that every commutative square like

$$ \begin{CD} 
A @>u>> B \\ 
@VfVV@VVgV \\
C @>>v> D
\end{CD} $$

i.e. every morphism $f \to g$ in the arrow category of ${\cal K}_v$ can be broken into

$$ \begin{CD} 
A @>u>> B \\ 
@Ve_fVV@VVe_gV \\
X @>>> Y \\
@Vm_fVV @VVm_gV\\
C @>>v> D
\end{CD} $$

and the central arrow exists, making both squares commutative.

Now, consider a similar square, but in the double category $\cal K$:

$$ \begin{CD} 
A @>\mathfrak u>> B \\ 
@VfVV@VVgV \\
C @>>\mathfrak v> D
\end{CD} $$ where now $\mathfrak u,\mathfrak v$ are proarrows. In general, it doesn't seem to be true that the factorisation of $f,g$ in

$$ \begin{CD} 
A @>\mathfrak u>> B \\ 
@Ve_fVV@VVe_gV \\
X @. Y \\
@Vm_fVV @VVm_gV\\
C @>>\mathfrak v> D
\end{CD} $$

induces a proarrow $\mathfrak h : X \to Y$ that factors *the cell* with boundary $\mathfrak u,f,\mathfrak v,g$ as the pasting of two contiguous *cells* sharing $\mathfrak h$ as common horizontal side.

Let's say that a factorisation system $({\cal E},{\cal M})$ on ${\cal K}_v$ is *pro-friendly* if it happens.

The trivial factorisation systems are evidently pro-friendly: is there a nontrivial example? A concrete example of a double category of this kind is fairly rich with structure: the proarrow equipment ${\sf Cat}/{\sf Prof}$, where vertically one takes functors, horizontally profunctors.

I know a few functorial factorisation systems on $\sf Cat$:

1. comprehensive: initial / discrete fibration;
2. folk: injective equivalence / isofibration (this is a WFS, but I only need functoriality to state the property);
3. boff: bijective on objects / fully faithful.

Do you see an easy counterexample that shows they are not pro-friendly? I struggled a little bit with the first and with the possibility to find companions and conjoints for every vertical map, hoping that that would help, but I have no clues.